# whats the path of a file inside vendor assets

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zclip

this might be an easy one. 
Im using a plug in to copy text to my clipboard (zclip) that requires me to add a .swf file to my assets.

I added a folder under my vendor>assets>zClip> zclip.swf

then on my javascript it requires that I add the path. what path should I use?

```
    $("#copy-button").zclip({
        path: "",
        copy:$('.copy_tag').text()
    });
```

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check that the path is being included by running `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in a console. If you see it, try putting `<%= asset_path 'zclip.swf' %>` in one of your views. It'll probably just be `'assets/zclip.swf'`

Answer (score 0):

Everything in any of the asset paths (app/assets, vendor/assets, any gems or engines) end up as `/assets/<resource path>` eventually. So in your case the path would be `/assets/zClip/zclip.swf`